# Is it possible to declare a field somehow local to its property

Tags: c#, properties, encapsulation

Usually I am trying to use automatic properties as much as possible. But often I need to do extra stuff in the setter, and sometimes even in the getter. When I include a field then, which backs the property, it always bothers me that the backing field is accessible to all methods, not just the property.

The temptation is quite high, to modify the field directly some time in the future, circumventig the encapsulation of the property. Is there any way in C# to enforce the field to being used only in the property getters or setters? Something to the effect of declaring it local to the property like (I know this doesn't work):

```
class Foo
{
    public string Name
    {
        string nameField; // how nice if a local decalaration was possible

        get {/* probably something else to do here */ return nameField;}
        set {/* probably something else to do here */ nameField = value;}
    }

    public void someStupidMethod()
    {
        nameField = "Donald"; // how nice if the compiler would throw up here
    }
}
```

Comment: No there is no way to do that. I suspect naming the field `_doNotUseOutsideThePropertyNameField` might get the job done though. :)

Comment: @mjwills: actually this is a pretty good idea... :-D

Comment: @RayKoopa: true, it's a clear duplicate. But at least I am glad, Jon Skeet agrees that it would be a cool feature.

Comment: I'd rather recommend naming such fields postfixed with `Backing` or `BackingField` aka `_nameBacking`. That makes the intention clear and shorter without sounding like arbitrary limitations (how often have I seen people ignoring stuff like `doNotUse` thinking they know better). I do like your syntactical idea though, but it is sadly not possible at this time.

Comment: Don't smoke near the explosives :-D

Comment: The reason I like `doNotUse` (at the front) rather than `Backing` (at the back) is that intellisense is more likely to match the latter than the former. `doNotUse` is not bulletproof, but you really do need to go out of your way to get it.

Comment: I thought about that, but then the new IntelliSense searches substrings anyway rather than from the start. You could use backing as a prefix too.

Comment: I have opted for the BackingField variant now. For me it's safe enough, I hope.